# Account Roll up of contacts meeting certian criteria

Tags: trigger, batch, roll-up-summary, schedulebatch

I need to know at the account level how many contacts under this account match certain criteria.  In this case, its whether or not a custom checkbox field is checked.  So for instance, if under Acme account there were 7 contacts, and 3 of those contacts had the custom checkbox checked, I could see 3 as the number of contacts meeting this criteria on the account record.

I know we cant use contacts in rollup fields on the account.  I have a two different ideas on how to accomplish this.

- I could write a trigger on insert and update of contact to update a
  field on the account object.
- I could write a scheduled batch job to run nightly to update
  this information

Is there a better way to accomplish this with workflows?  If not, which of these methods is the best approach?  Anyone else run into this requirement and solved it in a different way?

Comment: I've implemented similar roll-ups with http://www.anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility/

Comment: That's a pretty slick utility.  I think I'll implement it.  Thanks, if you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've implemented similar roll-ups with this roll-up summary utility: [anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility](http://anthonyvictorio.com/salesforce/roll-up-summary-utility). This has allowed me to create "dynamic" roll-ups, such as summing data from the last 3 full calendar months, or year-to-date without needing to constantly change the field definition.

Comment: Could you add in the code or important part of it here. The link seems to be down.:(

Answer (score 1):

One thing i consider in these scenarios is possibility of deletion of record .If thats possible i would simply rule out option of workflow as on delete we cannot fire any workflow rule .

I would use both trigger and batch solution as well for your case as trigger is for real time update and reason i would keep batch is if something happens or due to some reasons the trigger did some wrong  calculation(Assume someone switched off the trigger mistakenly or some fields were later made required or there was data type change to fail the trigger) then the batch will run and make the calculations proper .